# aws-sdk-v2 for ec2 listing

Tags: ruby, scripting, aws-sdk

is this right way to do this ? Please help if there are other better ways to do this?

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
require 'aws-sdk'

client = Aws::EC2::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2')
resp = client.describe_instances
resp.reservations.each do |node, num = 0|
  puts "#{node.instances[num].instance_id}"
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just wanted to list all the instances.

Answer (score 0):

```
  credential = {
                 access_key_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                 secret_access_key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                 region: 'us-west-2'
               }

  Aws.config.update aws_credential

  Aws::EC2::Client.new.describe_instances.reservations.each do |instance|
    p instance[0].instance_id
  end
```